# Can I shorten the room insertion time using RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing an android app. I'm having a hard time writing code that adds a to-do list to a calendar. Let me show you the code first.

```
private fun addTodoList(entity: MyTodo) {
    val start = Calendar.getInstance()
    val end = start.clone() as Calendar
    end.time = SimpleDateFormat("MM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).parse(Date.END_OF_DAY)!!

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        val id = MyDatabase.getInstance(mContext).getTodoDao().insert(entity)
        val dao = MyDatabase.getInstance(mContext).getCalendarDao()

        do {
            val date = ymd.format(start.timeInMillis)
            val item = CalendarEntity(date, id.toInt())
            dao.insert(item)
            start.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        } while (start.timeInMillis <= end.timeInMillis)
    }
}
```

This is the code that inserts the `Todo` created by the user through `TodoDao`, and inserts the value into `CalendarDao` from today to `Date.END_OF_DAY` (I randomly designated this value as "December 31, 2025"). But the insertion speed through `CalendarDao` was quite slow. There is no inconvenience in the UI, but if the user completely terminates the app from the task during insertion, it will be terminated without inserting data until the end. It has been said that using `RxJava` can solve this problem, how can you solve it? Even if it's not `RxJava`, if there is a way to solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: Why are you even doing this? Maybe it would be better to consider saving the item with just start and (optionally) end date - and adjust queries to return data accordingly. If you are saving the same item to DB for each and every day, especially on mobile, your users won't be much happy as their device will run out of space. What happens if they decide to change the title? Or the start/end date? I think you are very much complicating that even to yourself and to future maintainers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  `Dispatchers.Default` to   `Dispatchers.IO`

This is a database operation and it should be handled on an `IO` thread, `Default` is a real heavy duty CPU thread.

Using `RxJava` is a good way to standardize your database interactions, it allows you to stay off the UI thread and setups up an Observer pattern to allow you to react to the data as you get it instead of waiting for it.

If they close the app while this operation is happening there is not much you can do, as this is handled under 1 transaction. As such the actual changes to the database are only handled at the end, meaning if the operation doesn't complete nothing gets inserted. But you also don't want to do this 1 transaction at a time because that is extremely slow. Its a reliability vs speed question.